# Loop through NextSibling DIV tagname Selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

In my HTML page, at this link https://pastebin.com/nu0dLvch
There are elements which have the id "DetailSection1" .. And I am trying to loop through the div tags which is after this id (the tags are five in count)
This is my try but didn't work for me

```
Dim v, post As Object, sibling As Object, i As Long
Set post = .FindElementsByCss("#DetailSection1")
For i = 1 To post.Count
    'Debug.Print post.Item(i).Attribute("outerHTML")
    Set sibling = post.Item(i).NextSibling
    Select Case sibling.NodeType
    Case 3
        v = sibling.NodeValue
    Case 1
        v = sibling.innerText
End Select

Debug.Print v
Next i
```

How can I loop through the five tags of DIV after this element of id "#DetailSection1"?

[image]

This is what I got as Arabic characters (Green is what I got while the yellow part is the correct characters)
[image]

Comment: The `id` attribute needs to be unique. It will still render properly but it's wont help with automation.

Comment: I know that id attribute should be unique but in the HTML are not unique and it is related to the records (each record for student) has id attribute and below that there are DIV tags (5 divs) which contains the data for each student.

Comment: Does `.FindElementByCss` return the number of records your expecting?

Comment: Yes, it returns the same number of records when I used `.Count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) If you want to use your logic then you will need to loop the `nextElementSiblings` until empty string is returned (rather than hardcode loop to 5). n.b.  I am using [nextElementSibling](https://www.w3.org/TR/ElementTraversal/#attribute-nextElementSibling) as I want the next sibling element node (node type 1).

**W3C Element Traversal Specification**

> 2.4. nextElementSibling:
>
> Accessing this attribute of an element must return a reference to the sibling node of that element which most
>   immediately follows that element in document order, and which is of
>   nodeType 1, as an Element object. If the element on which this
>   attribute is accessed does not have any following sibling nodes, or if
>   none of those following sibling nodes are element nodes, then this
>   attribute must return null.

This is an `ie` version, as I can test that, but should be easy to translate. `Selenium Basic` does not expose `nextElementSibling` method so you can still use `HTMLDocument` and `querySelector` to access from page html, via transfer from `pageSource` of webdriver (assuming no non-trivial html changes with `MSHTML.HTMLDocument`), or switch to `nextSibling` traversal; and add in `nodeType = 1` test during loop.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TEST()

    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

    ie.Visible = True  
    'ie.Document.Charset = "utf-8"  ''< may be require for handling Arabic chars. Not required with my settings.
    ie.Navigate2 "file:///C:/Users/<User>/Desktop/Test.html"

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

    Dim startNodes As Object, node As Object, firstNode As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, c As Long, r As Long

    Set startNodes = ie.document.querySelectorAll("#DetailSection1")

    r = 1

    For i = 0 To startNodes.Length - 1           'you could determine number of child divs to get num columns then use step 5 loop or mod to write out in rows and cols
        Set node = Nothing
        firstNode = True
        c = 1
        Do

            If firstNode Then
                Set node = startNodes.item(i).nextElementSibling
            Else
                Set node = node.nextElementSibling
            End If
            If node.innerText <> vbNullString Then
                c = c + 1  'you may need backwards loop to reverse output columns
                ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c) = Trim$(node.innerText)
            End If
            firstNode = False
        Loop Until node.innerText = vbNullString
        r = r + 1
    Next

    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

---

2) You could dynamically pick up class and use a combination of css attribute selectors to hopefully correctly target nodes of interest. I have read in your html from file via IE. It is shaky due to reliance on attributes and relationships. It is all nested tables with few distinguishing features and likely dynamic attribute values. If not dynamic, then hardcode value for `targetClass` as `ad66b5fc2d-4b59-45e6-b104-e14dfb5b1dac-0`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer

    ie.Visible = True

    ie.Navigate2 "file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test.html"

    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

    Dim startNodes As Object, i As Long, targetClass As String, cssSelector As String

    targetClass = "." & ie.document.querySelector("#DetailSection1").nextElementSibling.className       ' "." & ie.document.querySelector("div[style*='center']").className

    cssSelector = targetClass & "[style*='center'], " & targetClass & "[style*='center'] ~ div[style*='text-align']"

    Set startNodes = ie.document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector)

    For i = 0 To startNodes.Length - 2 'you could determine number of child divs to get num columns then use step 5 loop or mod to write out in rows and cols

        ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = startNodes.item(i).innerText

    Next
    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

---

Untested selenium translation (can't test so written from my memory (eek!):

```
Dim startNodes As Object, i As Long, targetClass As String, cssSelector As String

targetClass = "." & .FindElementByCss("div[style*='center']").Attribute("class")

cssSelector = targetClass & "[style*='center'], " & targetClass & "[style*='center'] ~ div[style*='text-align']"

Set startNodes = .FindElementsByCss(cssSelector)

For i = 0 To startNodes.Count - 2 'you could determine number of child divs to get num columns then use step 5 loop or mode to write out in rows and cols

    ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = startNodes.item(i).Text

Next
```

You can explore whether you can get targetClass from (nodeType = 1):

```
.FindElementByCss("#DetailSection1").nextSibling.className  

.FindElementByCss("#DetailSection1").nextSibling.Attribute("class") '<== I think this
```

I'm sorry I can't test. I'm not sure those versions will work but would be good to know.

Ref:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62366101/6241235 @ [أبو عائشة ورقية ومحمد](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13741800/%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88-%D8%B9%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B4%D8%A9-%D9%88%D8%B1%D9%82%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D9%88%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF)

Comment: Thank you very much for this great and incredible efforts. I will study each line in this solution. As for the first point, the Arabic data is imported in non-understandable characters and I need each block of data (5 parts) to be in one row ..

Comment: Simply increment column instead of row. See edit. You may need to reverse column order by looping backwards. Not sure how comes out in your browser.

Comment: What about the Arabic characters ..?

Comment: It writes out Arabic characters for me but column order is reversed

Comment: https://tmpfiles.org/download/54775/Untitled.png You should be using selenium automated browser right? just use .FindElementsByCss method hopefully

Comment: I have updated the question to show you the output of code and the expected one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215907/discussion-between-qharr-and-yasserkhalil).

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I am very satisfied with the solutions presented by QHarr. But I am eager to discover and learn new skills, so I am trying on my side after studying well what QHarr presented and this is my try-on selenium

```
Sub Test()
    Dim bot As New ChromeDriver, a(1 To 1000, 1 To 5), post As Object, i As Long, j As Long
    With bot
        .AddArgument "--headless"
        .Get "file:///C:\Sample.html"
        Set post = .FindElementsByCss("#DetailSection1")
        If post.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To post.Count
                For j = 1 To 5
                    a(i, j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Trim$(post.Item(i).FindElementsByXPath("following-sibling::div")(j).Text))
                Next j
            Next i
            ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(post.Count, UBound(a, 2)).Value = a
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

** Note: I welcome any new and other ideas as I am eager to learn about different approaches.

Comment: Very nice. I was looking at xpath myself but didn't get as far as this. Do you need r? Isn't r just i?

Comment: You are right. I would use i directly and remove the variable r. Thanks a lot,