# Change Internet Explorer encoding using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

The internet explorer on my side is set to Auto-Select in Encoding from VIew menu. I would like to change the encoding to UTF-8 by VBA code ..
I tried such a line but seems not to work as expected

```
ie.document.Charset = "utf-8"
```

Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this code

```
Sub IEGetToKnow()
  Dim IE As InternetExplorer
  Set IE = New InternetExplorer
  With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate2 "http://www.google.com.eg"
     While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE:DoEvents:Wend
    .Document.Charset = "utf-8"
    .Refresh
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great solution.